# Due Diligence: Considering Octopus Deploy, Can System Center be used instead?

Tags: .net, deployment, octopus-deploy

I'm currently evaluating options for automated deployment of our applications (ASP.Net websites, WCF Services, etc.), and so far [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/) looks to be both low friction and reasonably priced. I was able to throw together a quick demo in a few hours, and showed it to my boss. He was impressed, but would like to know if we can do something similar using [Microsoft's System Center](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/server-cloud/system-center/default.aspx), since it is included in our MS license agreement. We're not currently using SC, but plan to start using it as a replacement for several products we're currently using for other tasks.

Getting to the point:

- Is it possible to deploy Web Sites/Services/etc. using some component of System Center?

  - How difficult is it to get started?
  - What are the prerequisites?

If there's some sort of guide out there that walks through the process, then all the better.

Comment: My group is in the same place you were in and I am leaning to octopus deploy if I go outside the System Center or InRelease. I am very interested in the route you choose and your thoughts now that you have done it.

Comment: We're sticking with Octopus Deploy for now, but other priorities have prevented it from being used in production yet. It's working very well for us in Dev/Test, and I'm looking forward to implementing their 2.0 version soon. I should probably collect my thoughts and experiences at some point and publish them so that others could potentially benefit.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Microsoft has purchased [InRelease](http://www.incyclesoftware.com/inrelease/) for this purpose. There is a preview release for 2013 [here](http://www.incyclesoftware.com/inrelease/inrelease-2013-preview/).

Comment: Since our shop is still on TFS 2010, we've opted for Octopus Deploy for the time being, and will evaluate InRelease later.

Comment: InRelease is compatible with TFS 2010, 2012, and 2013.

Comment: I should have been more clear. At the time, it only appeared that InRelease would be available from **Microsoft** for TFS 2013 and above. Since we would need to purchase the 2010 compatible version from InCycle separately, Octopus seemed like a more economical choice.

Comment: The licensing is forward-compatible -- Microsoft will honor licenses sold prior to the release of VS/TFS2013.